# Trying to get a Boolean in Java

Tags: java, math, static, boolean, range

I'm getting a compilation error in the following code, saying that operators can't be used for the boolean or double.

I want to return a boolean that indicates if `x` is in that range or not.

```
public static Boolean estaEnIntervalo (double x){           
    return (-5.0<=x<=2.0 || 0.0<x<=1.0 || 2.0<=x<5.0);              
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot combine relational operators this way, as you would in math.  How Java interprets `-5.0<=x<=2.0`:

`-5.0<=x` produces a `boolean`, but `boolean<=2.0` doesn't make sense.

You must create separate expressions for each bound.

```
return ((-5.0<=x && x<=2.0) || (0.0<x && x<=1.0) || (2.0<=x && x<5.0));
```

Answer (score 3):

-5.0<=x<=2.0 is not a valid expression. You need to use (-5.0 <= x) && (x <= 2.0), and similarly for the other checks too.

Also remember that Boolean is not the same as boolean. One is an object, and one is a primitive. As pointed out by SamTebbs33.

Answer (score 1):

You have to split each range into two conditions conbined with AND :

```
return ((-5.0<=x && x<=2.0) || (0.0<x&&x<=1.0) || (2.0<=x&&x<5.0));
```

Now, your condition checks if x if within any of three ranges :

```
[-------------------------------]
                      (----]    [------------]
-5                    0    1    2            5
```

Since these ranges overlap, so you can simply have a single range condition :

```
return (-5.0<=x && x<=5.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is an invalid boolean expression
`(-5.0 <= x <= 2.0)`

It must be changed to 
`(x <= 2.0 && x >= -5.0)`

In addition, you have to return a `Boolean`object.

```
return new Boolean((x <= 2.0 && x >= -5.0) || (x <= 1.0 && x > 0.0) || (x < 5.0 && x >= 2.0));
```

Otherwise, rearrange the expression like I did and change the return type to `boolean`